# C Define size of array inside main for a struct

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, global, sizeof

I looked at like 5 posts and still can't figure if this is possible....

```
typedef struct {
  long double xc;
  long double yc;
  long double zc;
  long double radio;
  long double Kd;
  long double Ka;
  long double Ks; // specular
  color fc; 
} SPHERE;

// *array_of_spheres;  // Original line omitted SPHERE

SPHERE *array_of_spheres;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int number_spheres = read_file(); 
//this return the number of spheres in the text file after fscanf

  array_of_spheres = malloc(sizeof(SPHERE)*number_spheres);
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

As you see I need list_of_spheres to be global, but I don't know the size until I read the file, so how can I initialize this array?

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
array_of_spheres = malloc(sizeof(SPHERE)*number_spheres);
```

I tried `sizeof(SPHERE)` AND `sizeof(*SPHERE)`.

The original code is in spanish
in the .h

```
typedef struct 
{
    long double xc;
    long double yc;
    long double zc;
    long double radio;
    long double Kd;
    long double Ka;
    long double Ks; // especular
    color fc;   
}esfera;

esfera *lista_esferas;
```

in the .c after i read a file and figure the number of spheres:

```
lista_esferas = malloc(sizeof( *esfera)*cantidad_de_esferas);

                               ^
```

RayT.c:29:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
  lista_esferas = malloc(sizeof( *esfera)*cantidad_de_esferas);

Comment: Wrong suggestion! And do not cast `malloc()`, that's bad practice.

Comment: Your Spanish code does not match your English code. Why do you have a `*` in `sizeof( *esfera)`??? What is that `*` doing there? It should be just `sizeof(esfera)` or better `sizeof  *lista_esferas`.

Comment: You need either `sizeof(esfera)` or `sizeof(*lista_esferas)` or `sizeof(lista_esferas[0])`.  You can't derefence a non-pointer, and `esfera` is a plain structure type, not a pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

Your global variable declaration for `array_of_spheres` is wrong, should be like below

```
SPHERE *array_of_spheres;
```

Comment: Do not translate your code, post your original code with the original issue.

Comment: ok i added the code in spanish.. dont see how it makes any deference, i just change the names to be more readable

Comment: @user2997958 your malloc is wrong should this `lista_esferas = malloc(sizeof(*lista_esferas) * cantidad_de_esferas);`

Comment: i got this new error:
RayT.c:40:68: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘esfera*’ [-fpermissive]
  lista_esferas = malloc(sizeof( *lista_esferas)*cantidad_de_esferas);

Comment: @user2997958 u using c++ compiler?

Comment: @user2997958: "Invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘esfera*’"? Such error can only be generated by a C++ compiler. Why are you using C++ compiler, yet claiming here that you are using C?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you help me with this, when compiling i use
g++ RayT.c -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -o RayTracer

based on a Mesa GLU example i found, im compiling on Linux Mint btw

Comment: @user2997958 there u go! u using g++ which is a C++ compiler! so to solve the error u mention, you just need to cast it `lista_esferas = (esfera *)malloc(sizeof(*lista_esferas) * cantidad_de_esferas);`  but it is bad idea to do this, u shuld use `new` instead of `malloc`